# Does not return the value in the field in custom object

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to display the number of opportunities with closed won in my custom object..i have no  error but it does not return the count...
please help

```
 trigger CountOpp on Opportunity (after update) {

List<Franchise_Agent__c> f1_qry = new List<Franchise_Agent__c>();
List<Opportunity> oppo_qry = new List<Opportunity>();
Set<ID> Ids = new Set<ID>();
Set<ID> opp_id = new Set<ID>();

for(Opportunity oppo : Trigger.new) {
    opp_id.add(oppo.Franchise_Agent__c);
}

f1_qry = [SELECT ID, Name FROM Franchise_Agent__c WHERE ID IN : opp_id];

for(Franchise_Agent__c agentid : f1_qry) {
    Ids.add(agentid.id);

}
     oppo_qry = [SELECT ID, Name, StageName, Franchise_Agent__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Franchise_Agent__c IN : Ids AND StageName = 'Closed Won'];
     system.assertequals(oppo_qry.size() + ' ','test');
     for(Opportunity oppor : Trigger.new){
       for (Franchise_Agent__c franch : f1_qry){
       franch.franchises__c = oppo_qry.size();
       }
    }


}
```

Comment: Your final loop list is type of `opportunity`, while you are trying to assign list items into `Franchise_Agent__c`.

Comment: I don't understand purpose of this code....
What it supposed to do?

Comment: I have to count all of the closed won opportunity of a franchise agent. It will be displayed in the franchise agent object. I have no error but it does not display.

Comment: @highfive what should I do? Im new to apex please bear with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your trigger like this. I've tested it.

```
trigger CountOpp on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    //Get all the agents affected by the change in opportunities    
    List<Franchise_Agent__c> agents = [SELECT Id, Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c,
        (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities__r WHERE StageName='Closed Won') 
        FROM Franchise_Agent__c 
        WHERE Id IN (SELECT Franchise_Agent__c FROM Opportunity Where ID in :Trigger.new)];

    //get the list of agents that have the changed number of Franchises that are 'Closed Won'
    List<Franchise_Agent__c> agentsToUpdate = new List<Franchise_Agent__c>();

    for(Franchise_Agent__c a : agents ){
        Integer closedWon = a.Opportunities__r.size();
        if(a.Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c != closedWon)
        {
            a.Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c = closedWon;
            agentsToUpdate.add(a);
        }   
    }

    if(agentsToUpdate.size() > 0)
        update agentsToUpdate;
}
```

Also, you shouldn't call SOQL inside FOR loops as there's a chance that your trigger will hit Governor Limits. I hope I helped.

Comment: the field is still empty.. what should i do?

Comment: what is your Total_Franchise_with_Closed_Won__c data type? mine is number

Comment: Yes, mine is number as well. Have you tried updating an Opportunity that has assigned Franchise_Agent and changing it to "Closed Won"? This is a trigger, so it will only fire after you update or insert Opportunities. All the old agents won't show any change unless their related Opportunity is updated. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Not a problem. Any time :)

Comment: how about if I want to track the number of opportunities of the franchise agent per month?

Comment: You could create a formula field with following formula: `Total_Franchise_With_Closed_Won__c / 12`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this line:

```
for(Franchise_Agent__c franch : Trigger.new)
```

its basicly:

```
for(Franchise_Agent__c franch : List <Opportunity>)
```

As you can seee it does not have sense - as you are trying to loop trought list with wrong type

Please check this code:

```
trigger CountOpp on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
        OppHelp.countOpp(trigger.new);
    }

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
        OppHelp.countOpp(trigger.new);
    }

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isDelete){
        OppHelp.countOpp(trigger.old);
    }
}

public without sharing class OppHelp{
    public static void countOpp(List<Opportunity> oppList){
        Set<Id> franchiseAgentIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Franchise_Agent__c> affectedFranchiseAgents;

        for(Opportunity opp : oppList) {
            if(opp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
                franchiseAgentIds.add(oppo.Franchise_Agent__c);
            }
        }

        affectedFranchiseAgents = [ SELECT Id, Name,
                                        (SELECT Id 
                                        FROM Opportunities__r // name of child relation
                                        WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won'
                                        )
                                    FROM Franchise_Agent__c 
                                    WHERE ID IN : franchiseAgentIds];


        for(Franchise_Agent__c fAgent : affectedFranchiseAgents) {
            fAgent.Franchises__c = fAgent.Opportunities__r.size();
        }
        update affectedFranchiseAgents;
    }
}
```

Comment: i no longer get the error but it does not return the number in my field

Comment: Its "after trigger" - this means any update you want to make need to be done manualy vide "update". Please post your current code and/or requirements - they someone may be able to help you.